# How to write given equation in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write equation  below in LaTex:
[image]

I wrote it :

```
r_{i,j}=min\lbrace\vert x_{i,j}$\bigotimes$ K_{p} \vert \: p=1 to 4\rbrace\;
```

but it giving error.
Please give suggestion to write it correctly.

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site! This is really nothing to do with `biblatex` or TeXmaker, so I've modified your tags a little. You can just have `\{` and `\}` for `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` and you should consider `\min`. Anyway your main problem is with `$ ... $` Your whole equation should be in math mode one way or another (probably easiest to have `$ ... $` around the whole equation) because many of these commands can only be used in math mode. You shouldn't then have `$ ... $` just around `\bigotimes` especially if you're in a math mode environment like `equation`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The entire expression, and not just the `\otimes` term, must be in math mode:

```
$r_{i,j}=\min \lbrace\vert x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \vert : p=1,\dots, 4 \rbrace$
```

Note that I would use `\otimes`, not `\bigotimes`. And, do write `\min` rather than just `min`.

*Addendum*: If you wanted to give more visual prominence to the curly braces that enclose the material to the right of the `=` symbol, you could enlarge them a bit via `\bigl` and `\bigr` modifiers:

```
$r_{i,j}=\min \bigl\lbrace\vert x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \vert : p=1,\dots, 4 \bigr\rbrace$
```

[image: $r_{i,j}=\min \bigl\lbrace\vert x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \vert : p=1,\dots, 4 \bigr\rbrace$]

Comment: why not also use `\lvert` and `\rvert`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- ... because the OP didn't indicate whether or not the  `amsmath` package was in use. :-) And, for the equation at hand, it turns out that there's no difference in output. That's why I left it at `\vert`.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    $r_{i,j}=\min\big\{\big| x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \big| : p=1,\dots, 4\big\}$   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, IMHO I would code the formula as follows:

```
\( r_{i,j}=\min
  \bigl\{\lvert x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \rvert : p=1,\dots,4\bigr\} \)
```

(I am assuming that the **amsmath** package is being used, of course).  But I noticed that in picture you posted the “min” operator is followed by a thin space; this can be obtained by writing

```
\( r_{i,j}=\min\,
  \bigl\{\lvert x_{i,j}\otimes K_{p} \rvert : p=1,\dots,4\bigr\} \)
```

But I do not recommend doing so.